# Decriptive Programming Multiple properties

Tags: html, hp-uft

I am using to UFT and having a problem in describing multiple properties for an object.

```
b_username = "html id:=txtUsername","type:=text"
```

Trying this has not helped me. Even tried the ";" delimiter but that too is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how to reference an object using Descriptive Programming.

You still use the UFT syntax of `Browser().Page().WebEdit()` (for example) and because you are trying to set an object reference you need the `Set` keyword.  Try something like:

```
Set b_username = Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").WebEdit("html id:=txtUsername","type:=text")
```

This will allow you to use `b_username` to reference the text box with the `html id` of `txtUsername`:

```
b_username.Set myUsernameValue
```

For a pretty good basic introduction to descriptive programming, check out [LearnQTP.com](http://www.learnqtp.com/descriptive-programming-simplified/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are more closing attempting to do is to build a [Description Object](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_descriptive_programming.htm).

You need something like the following:

```
'Creating a description object
Set btncalc = Description.Create()

'Add descriptions and properties
btncalc("type").value = "Button"
btncalc("name").value = "calculate"
btncalc("html tag").value = "INPUT"

' Use the same to script it
Browser("Math Calc").Page("Num Calculator").WebButton(btncalc).Click
```

This SO article has a good explanation of a little more advanced technique.

[How to create description object model at runtime in uft/qtp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013223/how-to-create-description-object-model-at-runtime-in-uft-qtp)

Please let me know if this clears up some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the below library for descriptive programming. It saves you from creating tons of descriptive objects. Check the usage in the link below.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/qtpuft-advanced-descriptive-programming/

To enter some value in the all the textboxes (no need to iterate)

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebEdit").SetValue "1"
```

To enter some value in a textbox whose name starts with ‘guru’

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebEdit,name:=guru.*").SetValue "1"
```

The above example can also be written as

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebEdit").WithRegExProperty("name:=guru.*").SetValue "1"
```

To get the fifth visible child object which has the name as guru.

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebEdit").WithRegExProperty("name:=guru.*").Index(4).Set "1"
```

To enter the values only in the visible text boxes

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebEdit").WithRegExProperty("name:=guru.*").VisibleChildObjects.SetValue "1"
```

To select all visible check boxes

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebCheckBox").VisibleChildObjects.SetValue "ON"
```

To get items count

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebCheckBox,type:=checkbox,name:=jqg_list.*").VisibleChildObjects.getCount()
```

To match certain property values

```
Browser("creationTime:=0").Page("micclass:=Page").getChildObjects("micclass:=WebEdit").WithRegExProperty("name:=guru.*").VisibleChildobjects().Set "1"
```

To give some delay between 2 ‘Set’ – [if required for something]

```
Browser(“creationTime:=0”).Page(“micclass:=Page”).getChildObjects(“micclass:=WebEdit”).WithRegExProperty(“name:=guru.*”).VisibleChildobjects().DelayEachSetBy(1).Set “1”
```